# When creating plpython3u function - Connection to the server has been lost

Tags: postgresql

I try to create some test Python function, like here:
https://www.enterprisedb.com/edb-docs/d/edb-postgres-advanced-server/user-guides/language-pack-guide/10/EDB_Postgres_Language_Pack_Guide.1.12.html

I executed successfuly

```
CREATE LANGUAGE plpython3u
```

I did copy file python3.dll into Postgres\pgsql\lib
But when I execute code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pymax (a integer, b integer) RETURNS integer AS 
$$
    if a > b:
      return a
    return b
$$ LANGUAGE plpython3u;
```

I get error "Connection to the server has been lost." and function is not created.
Python is well configured in my OS.
What can be the reason? Are there any logs in Postgres (windows). Where to search for them?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-logging.html https://www.endpoint.com/blog/2014/11/12/dear-postgresql-where-are-my-logs

Comment: They're supposed to be strings (paths), not the boolean `ON` value?

Comment: There must be some problem in your system that crashes PostgreSQL when Python is loaded. Consult the PostgreSQL log file.

Comment: An update to Bergi's reply: The second blog post "Dear PostgreSQL: Where are my logs?" has moved to: https://www.endpointdev.com/blog/2014/11/dear-postgresql-where-are-my-logs/

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. In my PostgreSQL log I found:

`Fatal Python error: initfsencoding: unable to load the file system codec
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'`

The solution (on Windows) was to configure environment variables `PYTHONHOME` and `PATH` ([source](https://www.enterprisedb.com/edb-docs/d/edb-postgres-advanced-server/user-guides/language-pack-guide/12/EDB_Postgres_Language_Pack_Guide.1.09.html)) (unfortunately, since modifying these system-wide wide is not desirable).

> **Configuring Language Pack on Windows**
>
> After installing Language Pack, you must tell the Python interpreter where to find Python:
>
> `set PYTHONHOME=C:\edb\languagepack\v1\Python-3.7`
>
> Then, use the following commands to add Language Pack to your search path:
>
> `set PATH=C:\edb\languagepack\v1\Python-3.7; C:\edb\languagepack\v1\Perl-5.26\bin; C:\edb\languagepack\v1\Tcl-8.6\bin;%PATH%`
>
> After setting the system-specific steps required to configure Language Pack on Windows,
>   restart the database server.